# Log user access on windows domain

Tags: logging, domain-controller, login

I want to log the user access to domain's computer. For example I would like to store datetime, username and computer for each login into a domain's computer. Is it possibile?
I'm using windows server 2012 as domain controller.

Comment: a lot of this is builtin but if you need permanent archiving of this stuff then you'll need a product like splunk..

Comment: This is not an utility to export to txt (and then I can import in a db) the event logs for user login?

Answer (score 1):

you will find the information you are looking for in the windows event log. have a look at the security eventlog. for logon and logoff information check the Event IDs 4624 and 4634.

you will find detailed information here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd772712%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The log on, log off information may be a bit complex to pour through.

For more readable logs you can make a logon/log off script that writes to a share.

Comment: I think it's not necessary two run a logon/logoff script on every Computer, because the information is stored in the Evnetlog on the DC. in my view it's better to write a script or program that export this Event Log information. i wrote a c# program for this a few weeks ago.

Comment: Does it store every user log-in on every DC?

Comment: It stores every domain user logon/logoff with client ip/name on the Logonserver DC so you had to run the script/program on every Global Catalog Server. I fully agree to your answer if you want to log Local User Logons.

Comment: With as script you could log it to the AD DFS